# ChartFX 7 Winforms - cannot edit control

Tags: c#, winforms, chartfx

I have a winforms form with a ChartFX 7 control on it and I am not able to click or select the control on the designer. The controls are not locked and the version is VS2015 with framework 4.0 selected. I cant even drag and drop the control onto a form. Does anyone know a way to fix this issue?
I've restarted/reinstalled (and created new solutions in vs2015) many times with the same result. Cannot click/select the control on the designer.

Comment: Can you create a Form class and add an instance of the control to it via Controls.Add(control)? And then update its properties accordingly? In other words, try taking the amateur designer crap out of the mix here for the moment to see if you can get it working programmatically first.

Comment: tried that way too. By creating an object and adding it manually while the form loads. It won't appear at runtime either way.

Comment: Could it perhaps be a 32 bit vs 64 bit issue? Maybe the control is the wrong version? Can't think of much else to suggest TBH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out VS2015 messed up some registry entries while installing the ChartFX plugin or the plugin did not copy the settings into the new framework version. I copied the settings manually into the new framework versions (in my case, copied it into 4.0 from 3.0) and it worked.

Below are the keys I created (moved ChartFX70 key from v3.0):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\ChartFX70
```